# The program return an offset exception when I am trying to open excel file with File Stream

Tags: c#, .net

I'm a C# .NET newbie, I'm using NPOI to read the `.xls` file, `.xls` file's size is 86KB, I used this method to read the file:

```
        public static void ReadXlsFile(string filePath)
        {
            using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                var workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
                var sheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(0);
                int rowIndex = 10;
                while (sheet.GetRow(rowIndex) != null)
                {
                    var row = sheet.GetRow(rowIndex);
                    Console.WriteLine("Row: {0} - Date: {1} - Class: {2} - Periods: {3} - Room: {4} - Time: {5}", rowIndex, row.GetCell(0).StringCellValue, row.GetCell(3).StringCellValue, 
                        row.GetCell(6).StringCellValue, row.GetCell(7).StringCellValue, row.GetCell(8).StringCellValue);
                    rowIndex++;
                }

            }
        }
```

And the program returns this exception: `Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.`

Can you explain this and give me a solution for this? Thanks.

Update: A more clear exception message:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.
   at System.IO.FileStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at NPOI.Util.IOUtils.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] b, Int32 off, Int32 len)
   at NPOI.POIFS.FileSystem.NPOIFSFileSystem..ctor(Stream stream)
   at NPOI.HSSF.UserModel.HSSFWorkbook..ctor(Stream s, Boolean preserveNodes)
   at NPOI.HSSF.UserModel.HSSFWorkbook..ctor(Stream s)
   at DataCrawler.Utils.AnalyzeXlsFile(String filePath) in D:\C#\actvnDataGetter\DataCrawler\Utils.cs:line 46
   at Console.Program.<Main>d__0.MoveNext() in D:\C#\actvnDataGetter\Console\Program.cs:line 17
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Console.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

Comment: Do you have 11th row in sheet? And the mentioned columns in the sheet?

Comment: @viveknuna of course, even I try to change `rowIndex` to 0, it doesn't change anything, and the exception returned on the line of `using` block

Comment: Are you reading the correct sheet?

Comment: @viveknuna I don't think I'm wrong at that step, I tried to change the sheet index value

Comment: You are sorting your while loop in first sheet from 11th row till the row which has first column as non empty, so you have to make sure all rows have the required columns

Comment: @viveknuna Thanks, but that's not the point, I think it is FIleStream, not the file or my code, Even if I try to run only `var workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);` The program still return the same exception

Comment: @JohnG [link] (https://sheet.zoho.com/sheet/officeapi/v1/12b8f7a3b33c787e0dce6e7eeae4cc1e99af2d25c674a6aeea98d7880036b07e3843bbf85a3af34409193bc7e8d5a6fd6f3594d7d93d52c930e595ffb6300ac7)

You can see it in this link

Comment: @JohnG The strange thing is, when I try to delete some row, it's work, I think the file size affect my code

Comment: @JohnG Thanks for your help. The program return exception on the line `var workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);` and I don't have any idea with this

Comment: @JohnG the same exception with what I described on my question

Comment: @JohnG I found the problem, NPOI 2.5.2 has a bug that makes me can't read file, I tried to downgrade to version 2.3.0, it worked like what you had said

Comment: @JohnG Thanks for your help! It gave me some useful suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out my problem's solution, just downgrade the NPOI version, I used 2.5.2 and it made me can't read my `.xls` files, so I downgrade to version 2.3.0 and it worked!